# How to move page numbers in a Google Doc?

Tags: google-docs

I am presently working on an application that very specifically requires me to have page numbers in the top left hand corner. As I do not have Word on my present computer, and am most familiar with Docs, I would like to use it for this application.

Unfortunately, the only options Docs seems to allow me off of the "Insert" tab are top and bottom right hand corners for page numbers. Is there a hack or app that grants a way around this? Or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to move page numbers in Docs. First, you need to click in the header or footer containing the page number. Then:

1. Justify left, right or centre to determine which side the number is on.
2. Move margin stop on the ruler (the little blue arrow and bar on the ruler, below the toolbar) to change how far to the side the number sits.
3. With the cursor placed before the number, press 'return' to move the number down.

Combining these can place the number pretty much anywhere.